# HTML5 local storage on reload not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To cut this short I have a row of checkboxes and I am trying to have it so that when one is clicked the options saves and remains on browser reload.

I have the array outputting into local storage, however it is not saving, here is the code so far:

```
<section class="column">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="BBCNews" class="checked" v-model="isBBCNews"><span>BBC News</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="BBCSport" class="checked" v-model="isBBCSport"><span>BBC Sport</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="TheTelegraph" class="checked" v-model="isTheTelegraph"><span>The Telegraph</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="TheIndependent" class="checked" v-model="isTheIndependent"><span>The Independent</span></label>
</section>

<section class="column">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="LadBible" class="checked" v-model="isLadBible"><span>Lad Bible</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="HackerNews" class="checked" v-model="isHackerNews"><span>Hacker News</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="Reddit" class="checked" v-model="isReddit"><span>Reddit</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="ProductHunt" class="checked" v-model="isProductHunt"><span>Product Hunt</span></label>
</section>
```

and here is the current javascript code

```
// Store services to local
  var enabledServices = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('enabledServices')) || {},

  $checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
      enabledServices[this.name] = this.checked;
    });

    localStorage.setItem("enabledServices", JSON.stringify(enabledServices));
  });

  // On page load
  $.each(enabledServices, function(key, value) {
    $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  });
```

and here is the array showing in local storage [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/ab531da1ab9dbd2de55486cc51d85a20)

I would like the option to disappear altogether but a simple false would do, currently when I refresh all checkboxes go back to there current state.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

By using the `Vue Persist` package for Vue https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persist I achieved what I needed.

Comment: Is the data still in local storage when you refresh? As in, is it being deleted, or is the JS not retrieving it properly?

Answer (score 1):

From your code there is no `id` assigned to the checkboxes, so the below will fail:

```
$("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
```

What you are writing to `localstorage` `key` is the name. Change to the following to get checkboxes by name and update the `checked` property.

```
 $("[name='" + key + "']").prop('checked', value);
```

```js
// Store services to local
var enabledServices = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('enabledServices')) || {},

$checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
$checkboxes.on("change", function () {
 $checkboxes.each(function () {
  enabledServices[this.name] = this.checked;
 });

 localStorage.setItem("enabledServices", JSON.stringify(enabledServices));
});

// On page load
$.each(enabledServices, function (key, value) {
 $("[name='" + key + "']").prop('checked', value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="column">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="BBCNews" class="checked" v-model="isBBCNews"><span>BBC News</span></label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="BBCSport" class="checked" v-model="isBBCSport"><span>BBC Sport</span></label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="TheTelegraph" class="checked" v-model="isTheTelegraph"><span>The Telegraph</span></label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="TheIndependent" class="checked" v-model="isTheIndependent"><span>The Independent</span></label>
</section>

<section class="column">
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="LadBible" class="checked" v-model="isLadBible"><span>Lad Bible</span></label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="HackerNews" class="checked" v-model="isHackerNews"><span>Hacker News</span></label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="Reddit" class="checked" v-model="isReddit"><span>Reddit</span></label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="ProductHunt" class="checked" v-model="isProductHunt"><span>Product Hunt</span></label>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried your example, here is the result. https://gyazo.com/ef60c6eb145d8c7e09c146b972aae126 any ideas?

Comment: I have verified the above code in chrome and it works fine. For IE, you may need to verify on your web server as it is throwing security error.

Comment: I am using Safari and I have tried in Chrome, but I'll give it another try.

Comment: Quick update. I got what I needed by using the `Vue Persist` package for Vue https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-persist